# Erlang, eunit and gen_server: context cleanup failed

Tags: unit-testing, erlang, eunit

I wrote some eunit test on my gen_server:

```
-module(st_db_tests).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

main_test_() ->
    {foreach,
     fun setup/0,
     fun cleanup/1,
     [
      fun db_server_up/1
     ]}.

setup() -> 
    {ok,Pid} = st_db:start_link(), Pid.
cleanup(Pid) -> 
    gen_server:call(Pid, stop).

db_server_up(Pid) ->    
    ?_assertMatch({[{<<"couchdb">>,<<"Welcome">>},{<<"version">>, _}]},
                  gen_server:call(Pid, test)).
```

When I make the test I have this:

```
./rebar eunit suite=st_db_tests skip_deps=true
==> site_stater (eunit)
Compiled test/st_db_tests.erl

... loading stuff ...

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 27-Jun-2011::12:33:21 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.127.0>},
                       {name,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
module 'st_db_tests'
*** context cleanup failed ***
::exit:{normal,{gen_server,call,[<0.99.0>,stop]}}
  in function gen_server:call/2


=======================================================
  Failed: 0.  Skipped: 0.  Passed: 1.
```

Seems like the test has passed, but there is en error in context cleanup, which is not right, right?)

How can I fix this?

PS: my gen_server

```
-module(st_db).

-behaviour(gen_server).
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Include files
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% External exports
-export([start_link/0]).

%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-record(state, {db_pid, couch_server_pid}).

%% ====================================================================
%% External functions
%% ====================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc Starts the server.
%%
%% @spec start_link() -> {ok, Pid}
%% where
%%  Pid = pid()
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({global, st_db}, ?MODULE, ["localhost", 5984, "site_stater"], []).

%% ====================================================================
%% Server internal functions
%% ====================================================================

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: init/1
%% Description: Initiates the server
%% Returns: {ok, State}          |
%%          {ok, State, Timeout} |
%%          ignore               |
%%          {stop, Reason}
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
init([Server, Port, DB]) ->
    couchbeam:start(),
    CouchServer = couchbeam:server_connection(Server, Port, "", []),
    {ok, CouchDB} = couchbeam:open_or_create_db(CouchServer, DB, []),
    {ok, #state{db_pid=CouchDB, couch_server_pid=CouchServer}}.


%% ====================================================================
%% DB manipulation functions
%% ====================================================================


%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: handle_call/3
%% Description: Handling call messages
%% Returns: {reply, Reply, State}          |
%%          {reply, Reply, State, Timeout} |
%%          {noreply, State}               |
%%          {noreply, State, Timeout}      |
%%          {stop, Reason, Reply, State}   | (terminate/2 is called)
%%          {stop, Reason, State}            (terminate/2 is called)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_call (test, _From, #state{couch_server_pid = Couch_server_pid} = State) ->
    {ok, Version} = couchbeam:server_info(Couch_server_pid),
    {reply, Version, State};


handle_call(stop, _From, State) -> 
    {stop, normal, State}.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: handle_cast/2
%% Description: Handling cast messages
%% Returns: {noreply, State}          |
%%          {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%          {stop, Reason, State}            (terminate/2 is called)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: handle_info/2
%% Description: Handling all non call/cast messages
%% Returns: {noreply, State}          |
%%          {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%          {stop, Reason, State}            (terminate/2 is called)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: terminate/2
%% Description: Shutdown the server
%% Returns: any (ignored by gen_server)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Func: code_change/3
%% Purpose: Convert process state when code is changed
%% Returns: {ok, NewState}
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

Comment: thanks everybody for such a good diving in erlang)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `handle_call/2` function, you're returning:

```
{stop, normal, State}
```

rather than something like:

```
{stop, normal, ok, State}
```

In other words, you're not replying to the call. The client then see the server terminating (with *normal* reason) and it cries.

Didn't try it, but this would be my first guess.

Comment: whoa, that helped. But I didn't get it. Manual says "the gen_server calls handle_call(Request, From, State) which is expected to return a tuple {reply, Reply, State1}."  There are 3 atoms, not 4, in feedback

Comment: But here you are using the `stop` tuple, which can have either 3 or 4 elements.

Answer (score 5):

It could be that the test finishes before the `gen_server` process has time to shut down. The `gen_server` is linked to the test process (because it is started with `gen_server:start_link/4`) and when the test finishes, the process is still running and is killed by EUnit.

Even if you return `ok` using `{stop, normal, ok, State}` as suggested by Roberto, the `gen_server` might be slower executing `terminate/2` than the test takes clean up.

I usually use such a function in my tests or teardowns to wait for processes:

```
wait_for_exit(Pid) ->
    MRef = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
    receive {'DOWN', MRef, _, _, _} -> ok end.
```

EUnit has a default timeout of 5000 ms that will be triggered if this function blocks for too long time.

Comment: Uhm, I would imagine that the terminate is function is called "before" returning the reply to the client. EUnit shouldn't kill a process which is still executing (Dimitry is issuing a stop request using a synchronous call). Also, in this case looks like the terminate function isn't that complicated, so I doubt it could take that long. In any case, I'm curious now :)

Comment: From the documentation: `If the function returns {stop,Reason,Reply,NewState}, Reply will be given back to From. [...] The gen_server will then call Module:terminate(Reason,NewState) and terminate.` Also, it doesn't matter if the terminate is simple, there can always be a race condition. EUnit will terminate the test process when the test code has finished executing. It doesn't care if there happens to be a linked process still alive somewhere.

Comment: From the gen_server code (if I'm looking at the right spot, I should have more time for this): [...] {stop, Reason, Reply, NState} -> {'EXIT', R} = (catch terminate(Reason, Name, Msg, Mod, NState, [])), reply(From, Reply), exit(R) [...]

Comment: @roberto: You are correct, it does indeed reply after `terminate/2` is called. However, during replying (and some internal `gen_server` debug code that's run afterwards), the test process might still exit. So the possibility for a race condition persists.

Comment: Furthermore, I would argue that it is always good practice to monitor processes that are supposed to die during testing. It's the best type of assertion you can have for such a test case.